# How to retrieve an installed file path from Registry

Tags: c#, registry, information-retrieval, registrykey

I would like to retrieve the path of an installed software from registry, I have tried different methods i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008331/retrieving-file-installation-path-from-registry) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315510/how-to-get-installed-software-path-from-registry) too but I faced the same error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an Object.

I observed that `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key)` returns `null` so I searched for the solution of this problem and found many, but those could not solve my issue. I want to continue with the following code:

```
string txt_filePath = "";

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bentley\AutoPIPE\V8i SELECTSeries 6 Ribbon Preview and Reporting");
object objRegisteredValue = key.GetValue("ApplicationPath");

txt_filePath = objRegisteredValue.ToString();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Stating the obvious but have you checked the registry to see if the key really exists ?

Comment: so with the existing code you are getting the key as null always?If so please check the registry.

Comment: @Joseph yes I am always getting the key null

Comment: @gideon I have checked the registry.

Comment: @ Itban that means there wont be an entry corresponding to your search in the registry.Please refer this link this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268715/registry-localmachine-opensubkey-returns-null

Comment: so this code should work fine ?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed Joseph's link should be read. Maybe you don't have permissions. Are you running the app under administrator? Or maybe you need to ask for elevation then.

Comment: @gideon I am running the app under administrator. Joseph's link looks useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe trouble is because of x64-bit machine?
Try this:

```
    var regView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
    var registry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, regView);

    var keyPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bentley\AutoPIPE\V8i SELECTSeries 6 Ribbon Preview and Reporting\RibbonUI.xml";
    var key = registry.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response but I am working on VS2008 having .NET version 3.5 , this code is not supported here.

Comment: You can find an alternative way for version 3.5 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217199/what-are-some-alternatives-to-registrykey-openbasekey-in-net-3-5